# Why adjusting the range of an RGB image with imshow(image,[]) does not work?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a double RGB image whose minimum value is -0.3471 and maximum value is 0.6485. I have tried to do `imshow(image)` and the result is the following:

[image]

To solve this problem, apart of summing the minimum value to the matrix of the image, I tried using `imshow(image, [])`, which theoretically, adjusts the range of the image to the range [0,1] in this case, but if I do that, the output image is the same.

Hence, I was wondering if the problem would be caused because is a RGB image, since with gray images it does its function. In fact, I have adjusted the range of the red layer using `imshow(image(:,:,1),[])`.

To summarize, I would like to adjust the range of this image using `imshow`(if possible).

Comment: The documentation says "`imshow(I,[])` displays the **grayscale image** I...", so I wouldn't expect it to work on RGB images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation for the `image` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.image-properties.html#budqsu__sep_shared-CData), it has a `CData` property that can be either a 2D array (gray-scale image), or a 3D array (RGB image). In the 2D case, the values are mapped (according to the `CDataMapping` property) through the specified color map to obtain RGB values to show on screen. In the 3D case, the values are directly used as RGB values to show on screen.

The `imshow` function just creates an `image` object with the input matrix as the `CData` property. The second argument (either `[]` or two explicit values) specify the [`CLim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-CLim) property of the containing axes, and thereby specify the scaling of the gray-value image. But as we saw before, this setting is ignored for RGB images.

To scale the color image, simply apply a linear mapping to it before display:

```matlab
a = min(image(:));
b = max(image(:));
imshow((image-a)/(b-a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cris' answer below is accurate, I was mistaken in my original post. I've removed that content even though it was accepted in favor of Chris' post.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @CrisLuengo. I confused myself thinking about this. You are correct. Thanks.

Comment: OP you should accept the answer from @CrisLuengo IMHO